# In Amazon SQS queue do we have a limit on number distinct group ids?

Tags: java, amazon-sqs

I am using SQS queue to solve a business need wherein,
Messages belonging to the same product needs to be executed strictly in a sequence but messages of different products can be executed in parallel.

I was hoping, if using my product_id as my group id will solve the problem but do we have any limitation on number of distinct group ids that SQS queue can hold?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does not look like it,  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html says:

> There is no quota to the number of message groups within a FIFO queue.

You only have to watch out not to have too many messages in-flight being processed by your consumers but not yet deleted, as https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagegroupid-property.html says:

> there can be a maximum of 20,000 inflight messages